# Using two string streams but not getting same result

Tags: c++, matrix, stringstream

I'm trying to make and print a matrix which will be getting its data from a text file. To be able to make the output aligned (i.e. like that of a matrix), I extracted the data from the files as strings first using stringstream to get the largest number of characters that an element will have in my matrix. Afterwards, I put this string back into another stringstream then extracted them to a double, as per the specifications of my project. The problem is, whenever I have data in my text file which are only separated by whitespace (NOT A NEW LINE), it only gets the first element of the line.

```
while(getline(file, line) && size < (rows*columns))
{
  stringstream s1(line);
  stringstream s2;
  string temp;
  double toAdd;

  while(s1 >> temp && size < (rows*columns)) 
  {
    if(temp.size() > columnWidth2)
      columnWidth2 = temp.size();

    s2 << temp;
    s2 >> toAdd;

    cout << "Size: " << size << "\nTo Add: " << toAdd << "\nTemp: " << temp << '\n';
    dataContainer[size] = toAdd;
    size++;
    s2.str(string());
  }
}
```

For example, I have a text file with this data:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6
7
8
9
10
```

If I output all the contents of my dataContainer, it reads:

```
1 1 1 1 1 6 7 8 9 10
```

instead of:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `dataContainer`?

Comment: @molbdnilo I have a two dimensional array as a member class. I'll use dataContainer to store the data, then transfer each element in the dataContainer array to my two dimensional array.

Comment: So, what *is* `dataContainer? What is its type? How do you define it? How you intend to use it in the future isn't very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you simply use

```
while(s1 >> toAdd && size < (rows*columns))
```

instead of

```
while(s1 >> temp && size < (rows*columns))
```

or, you can define the `stringstream s2` in the inside `while` block like this:

```
while(s1 >> temp && size < (rows*columns)) 
  {
    if(temp.size() > columnWidth2)
      columnWidth2 = temp.size();
    stringstream s2;
    s2 << temp;
    s2 >> toAdd;

    cout << "Size: " << size << "\nTo Add: " << toAdd << "\nTemp: " << temp << '\n';
    dataContainer[size] = toAdd;
    size++;
    s2.str(string());
  }
```

The best way to do this, is to add an `s2.clear()` after `s2.str("")`, `clear()` can reset the error state in the stringstream(in this case: eof)... because you called `operator>>` right after `operator<<`, `s2` reached to end-of-file and had the eof state set. According to c++ Refference, if you attempt to read end-of-file, you fail, and then "fail state" will be set up. This is the reason why `s2` can only gets the first element. Here are the codes to modify:

```
  while(s1 >> temp && size < (rows*columns)) 
  {
    if(temp.size() > columnWidth2)
      columnWidth2 = temp.size();
    s2 << temp;
    s2 >> toAdd;

    cout << "Size: " << size << "\nTo Add: " << toAdd << "\nTemp: " << temp << '\n';
    dataContainer[size] = toAdd;
    size++;
    s2.str(string());
    s2.clear(); //it can clear the eof state
  }
```

Comment: Putting stringstream s2 inside the while loop worked! Tbh, I don't know why, but it does.